# Why Tomcat 8.5 option allowLinking=true makes startup faster

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to upgrade a web application from  Java 7/tomcat 7  to Java8/Tomcat 8.5.

Everything works well but tomcat startup time is twice slower on tomcat 8.5 (2min) than in tomcat7 (1 min). The most unbelievable is that using option `allowLinking=true` in my  context.xml makes my tomcat 8.5 starts quickly (about 1 min)

My problem is  that I'm running on **windows** and tomcat 8.5 documentation about this option says

> This flag MUST NOT be set to true on the Windows platform

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/resources.html

Does anybody have an explanation ? 
And should i use this option on my tomcat (windows)  against apache recommendation ...

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read about the security implications in the linked docs ? That should help answering your question.

Comment: I found nothing except "it will disable case sensitivity checks, allowing JSP source code disclosure, among other security problems." Not very clear ...

Answer (score 0):

It's simple Windows doesn't manage symlinks like in unix systems! one more point to use unix server system !